# Friend Spawning underground and nothing is moving

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I made a server and when my friend entered the server she spawned underground, and when she got out nothing moved, I tried giving her operator privileges but that did not work.

Comment: what do you mean by nothing is moving?

Comment: Got a list of information I need from you to help get an answer: What do you mean nothing is moving (as Arperum asked), what kind of server are you running, any plug-ins your using, have you tried restarting the server, has your friend tried relogging. Gotta give us more then just a vague problem. Maybe some logs of what happens when your friends logs on, or a screenshot from your friend wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Are you using LAN? (Are you in the same house, connected to the same network?) I don't know if this might impact the problem, but it might be something to be aware of.

Answer (score 5):

"Nothing moving" means that the network connection between your friend and the server is way, way too slow to play.

If you're running this server over your home network, there could be all kinds of reasons why it's slow, but the most likely is that the upstream connection (how data goes *to* the Internet, as opposed to downloading from it) provided by your Internet Service Provider is low-bandwidth and/or high-latency. This is typically the case on home networks unless you pay for more expensive service, because "normal" home Internet usage downloads a lot of data but sends very, very little. Either of high-latency or low-bandwidth will make it hard or impossible for the server to send updates to your friend in real-time; it's like trying to drink through a tiny straw when your friend's Minecraft needs to slurp from a firehose to run properly.

Answer (score 1):

Their are a few variables that may affect this.

If you are running the server from a home network, it is most likely that either yours or her internet connection is not fast enough. If she is able to play on majority of other server perfectly fine then it is most likely your internet connection. What is causing this problem is known as the upload speed which refers to sending information from your network. I recommend doing a [speed test](http://www.speedtest.net/) and if your upload rate is less than 1Mbps, don't bother hosting a server. If she can't play any other server than it is most likely her end that is having download issues.

The other problem may be lack of memory to run the server. Generally a server requires a fair bit of memory to run smoothly especially with plugins installed. For a 2 person server I personally recommend at least 1GB of RAM dedicate to the server. If you are running a x86 OS I recommend upgrading to x64 as it allows you to allocate more RAM (x86 OS == 1GB MAX dedicated RAM). This can be expensive however and you must be sure that your computer can handle x64. If it can't, it is highly likely that your computer does not meet the requirements to run a server. Also, if it is possible, don't run the server on the same computer as you are playing minecraft on. If you decide to allocate more RAM, your computer may lag and be impossible to play minecraft. This won't be the case if you keep the RAM the same as when you normally play Minecraft as single player runs an internal server while you play anyway.

In conclusion it is generally the Memory allocated to the server and the upload speed of your network to the internet that causes no movement to be seen on the clients computer.

Comment: All good, except the part about playing on the same system as the server: this is how single-player Minecraft normally works, so it's actually no more resources than normal. If you can play lag-free singleplayer, you can host a server and play multiplayer on the same machine just fine, at least in terms of processor and RAM.

Comment: @seven I don't know whether that is true or not. It used to be the case that single player did NOT use a server, but that was changed (so I can see where pie got it from), but even now I think that using the same machine to play and host may increase the load still, even though connection might not change. I'm no expert though, so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @TheUgly Using the same machine works fine. The internal server and external server are nearly identical (they are created from the same codebase internally at Mojang), so there's almost no performance difference between a client running singleplayer and a client connecting to a locally-hosted server. I've done it often enough, and haven't noticed any problems that would contradict that.

Comment: Sorry it has been a while since I have really payed attention to Minecraft mechanics. I just remembered hosting a server off a netbook and playing at the same time a few years ago... It was horrible...